# Google Firebase Auth integration with Lotus Notes

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, lotus-notes

I am currently working on my Bachelors project, developing android app.

I want to use google firebase, since it provides a useful auth service. 
This app is for company that uses Lotus Notes (IBM Lotus Notes) as its e-mail service. 
Since firebase allows easy integration with many platforms, then i started to wonder **if there is a way to connect firebase with Lotus?** *Reminder- that i dont have access to Lotus DB or any other information*

Has anyone ever tried something like this? Or anything similar? Maby there is other ways i could create this auth?

I dont want to create a registration for my app since only the users in this company will use my app. Thats why i need them only to log in using e-mail that they already have in company.

Any information would be useful. Thank you.

Comment: If Firebase exposes an LDAP interface, you can make use of that with Directory Assistance.  If not, then you can potentially "roll your own" with Domino ISAPI, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: to me this sounds the other way round - android uses firebase for authentication that automagically authenticates Notes users. The path could be: user authenticates with Domino and receives a token (generation to be programmed), then sends token to firebase [signInWithCustomToken()] and gets logged in.